# How can I use online datasets for segmented objects

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm sorry if this is a simple question...but may I ask how can I use online datasets to obtain segmented object images (and hence be able to generate masks from it)? I'll need both the segmented object and the masks afterwards.

For example, I need to use datasets that will produce results on the right:

[image: Image taken from: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Example-of-GrabCut-segmentation_fig2_282740894]

Image taken from: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Example-of-GrabCut-segmentation_fig2_282740894

I don't really want to segment images myself and would rather use categorised datasets instead.So basically, I'll want to be able to search for an object type (e.g. bikes) and have a large set of segmented bikes. (Basically, have large sets of segmented object images grouped and stored by categories.)
I know that COCO dataset has categorised and annotated objects. But I'm not sure how to use it...Or if there's better ways of achieving my goal, what would it be? Would someone please help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should take a look to mask-rcnn or deeplabv3+ these two algorithm can provide you segmentation mask that you can latter if you want refine by using approaches such as densecrf or grabcut.
Both (mask-rcnn and deeplabv3+) exist with pretrained model on MS-COCO so you just have to modify an example for using them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I don't have any images at all so I'm trying to use an available dataset. But I'm afraid the COCO dataset api is too complicated for me to use..there's a lot of installation errors currently :(

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is something you should spend a bit of time on.
If there is a docker folder in the code you try to execute you try to work with the docker image.
Otherwise if you have a workable example try to modify it in order to adapt it to your situation.
If you do not have a docker image nor a workable example the best to understand where the error come from and make it work.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! :)